# Creating index/pk in a huge table is taking too long. I am using Oracle. How do I know if it is going well?

Tags: oracle, indexing, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I have a really huge table, with ~200 million rows. It had no index/pk at all. Selects in this table were (obviously) running slow. I decided to create a PK using 3 columns. I did it in a test environment that has a smaller version of this table and it worked like a charm.

So, before going home i did a 
ALTER TABLE HUGETABLE
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_HUGETABLE PRIMARY KEY (ID1, ID2, ID3);

I expected it to run over the night, but it has been already over 24 hours and it still running.

I know if i had kept the Session Id before starting my query i would be able to track it at V$SESSION_LONGOPS. But i didn't.

Is there any way to check how is my query going or how long will it still take?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should still be able to query V$SESSION_LONGOPS.  If you run something like

```
SELECT sid, serial#, start_time, sofar, totalwork, time_remaining, message
  FROM v$session_longops
 WHERE time_remaining > 0
```

you'll probably see only one session that started yesterday and the other columns should corroborate that with indications that the session has done a lot of work.  The MESSAGE should also indicate something like a full scan on HUGETABLE.

Comment: I couldnt find it. I found a lot of process going on, but couldnt identify mine. So I gave up and cancelled it :)
I will stop everything during the weekend and try it again. This time I will get the session id before starting the job.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Next time, define the index with PARALLEL n, where n is some acceptable degree of parallelism on your system.  When done, alter the index to NOPARALLEL.  Also, if you aren't using Data Guard and can take a backup of the database when done, use the NOLOGGING clause.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to remember your session id to monitor a statement's status. As Justin suggested, you shouldn’t have too many long running queries since previous day. You can specify start time as well to narrow down the results.

```
select * from V$SESSION_LONGOPS where time_remaining > 0 and start_time > <'your run date/time here'>;
```

Besides 'PARALLEL n' option, you should consider using 'ONLINE' option as well if you are creating (or rebuilding) an index while concurrent read/write are taking place on HUGE TABLE.